# Java lottery program counter

Tags: java

I need my lottery program to count the number of times 0,1,2,3,4 or 5 numbers match after 10 runs, then display them. It is also supposed to keep track of the total jackpot by adding a certain amount to the jackpot depending on how many numbers won. My problem is that is is counting this correctly for each individual run but not for all ten runs total. here is what I have.

```
package assignment5;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 import java.util.Random;
 public class assignment5
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
    {
    lottery pic=new lottery();
    pic.Get_player_numbers();
    pic.Get_jackpot_number();
    pic.Check_winner ();

    pic.Write_data();

}}
    }
    class lottery
{

int[] picks= new int[5];
int[] cpick=new int[5];
int i;
int j,c;
int match=0;

void Get_player_numbers ()

{
    int ctemp,cdupflag=0;
    for(j=0;j<=4;++j)
    {
        //YOU DO NOT NEED THE CNUMBERFLAG
        //IF YOU GENERATED THE NUMBERS CORRECLTY, THE COMPUTER WILL NOT GENERATE ONE ABOVE 99 OR LESS THAN 1
       cdupflag=0;
        while(cdupflag==0)
         {
            ctemp = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*99)+1;
            cdupflag=1;
            for(c=0;c<=j;++c)
               {
                 if(ctemp==cpick[c])
                    {
                     cdupflag=0;
                    }
                }//inner for loop
            if(cdupflag==1) 
                   cpick[j]=ctemp;
          }

    }
    String Jackpot="User Lottery numbers are: "+"\n";
    //String computer = "";
    for(j=0;j<=4;++j)
    {
        if(j==4)
            Jackpot=Jackpot+cpick[j];   
        else
            Jackpot=Jackpot+cpick[j]+"-";
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Jackpot,"Output:",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}

//void jackpot()
void Get_jackpot_number()
{

    int ctemp,cdupflag=0;
    for(j=0;j<=4;++j)
    {
        //YOU DO NOT NEED THE CNUMBERFLAG
        //IF YOU GENERATED THE NUMBERS CORRECLTY, THE COMPUTER WILL NOT GENERATE ONE ABOVE 99 OR LESS THAN 1
       cdupflag=0;
        while(cdupflag==0)
         {
            ctemp = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*99)+1;
            cdupflag=1;
            for(c=0;c<=j;++c)
               {
                 if(ctemp==cpick[c])
                    {
                     cdupflag=0;
                    }
                }//inner for loop
            if(cdupflag==1) 
                   cpick[j]=ctemp;
          }
    }
    String Jackpot="Computer Lottery numbers are: "+"\n";
    //String computer = "";
    for(j=0;j<=4;++j)
    {
        if(j==4)
            Jackpot=Jackpot+cpick[j];   
        else
            Jackpot=Jackpot+cpick[j]+"-";
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Jackpot,"Output:",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

}


void Check_winner ()
{

    for(int i=0;i<=4;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=4;++j)
        {
            if(picks[i]==cpick[j])
            {
                match=match+1;
            }
        }
    }

}


void Write_data ()
{
    String print = "";
    int jackpot = 2500000;
    int counter0 = 0;
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int counter3 = 0;
    int counter4 = 0;
    int counter5 = 0;

    if(match==0)
    {
        counter0++;
        print=print+"There is no match"+"\n";
        print=print+"please try again "+"\n";
        jackpot=jackpot+25000;
    }
    else
    if(match==1)
    {
        counter1++;
        print=print+"There is one match"+"\n";
        print=print+"You won 100 Dollars "+"\n";
        jackpot=jackpot+100000;

    }
    else 
        if(match==2)
        {
            counter2++;
            print=print+"There are two matches"+"\n";
            print=print+"You won 1,000 Dollars"+"\n";
            jackpot=jackpot+250000;
        }
        else
            if(match==3)
            {
                counter3++;
                print=print+"There are three matches"+"\n";
                print=print+"You won 10,000 Dollars "+"\n";
                jackpot=jackpot+500000;
            }
            else
                if(match==4)
                {
                    counter4++;
                    print=print+"There are four matches"+"\n";
                    print=print+"You won 100,000 Dollars "+"\n";
                    jackpot=jackpot+1000000;
                }
                else
                    if(match==5)
                    {
                        counter5++;
                        print=print+"There are five matches"+"\n";
                        print=print+"You won "+jackpot+" Dollars"+"\n";
                        jackpot=2500000;
                    }
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,print,"Output:",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    System.out.println("zero matchers occured " +counter0+ " times");
    System.out.println("The current jackpot is " +jackpot+ "");
}
 }
 //end of class lottery
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not sure to understand everything as your code is a little messy and uncommented, you should try to clear it, it will be easier for you to understand and to find errors.

Concerning the problems that I am seeing:

- If I correctly understand you want to keep the "Jackpot" over the 10 rounds. This is not happening because in your main function you are doing

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
  {
      lottery pic = new lottery();
      ....
  }
  ```

Therefore you are creating a NEW lottery for each run and it replace the previous lotery by an empty one at each runs. Maybe this instead would work:

```
    lottery pic = new lottery();
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
    {
        ....
    }
```

- As well be careful to your variables "match" in your lotery class. At the end of "Write_data" I would advice you to do "match = 0;" otherwise matches will not restart at 0 for each run